# jQuery-ui dropdown add value to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using jQuery-UI selectmenu and need to add the value data to the span that gets created via jQuery.

Link to source: [ui.selectmenu.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/branches/labs/selectmenu/ui.selectmenu.js?r=3816)

If I change line 292 to be:

```
this.newelement.prepend('<span class="'+self.widgetBaseClass+'-status" value="'+ selectOptionData[this._selectedIndex()].value +'">'+ selectOptionData[this._selectedIndex()].text +'</span>');
```

and add in the value=" " portion I get the span to display value but its only the first value and does not change when clicking through the drop down.

I must be missing something to add to the js to have the value updated onlick for other select options??

My select form is:

```
        <select name="sample" id="sample">
            <option value="1">Sample1</option>
            <option value="2">Sample2</option>
            <option value="3">Sample3</option>
            <option value="4">Sample4</option>
        </select>
```

And script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       
        $('select#sample').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
        });
</script>
```

Project homepage: [jQuery-UI](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu)